# Choose Random Item from JSON Response

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "category1": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #1"
    }
  ], 
  "category2": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #2"
    }, 
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #3"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get a random item from this response by reading through both categories?

My JSFiddle here works for Category 2. But I don't know how to read both categories: http://jsfiddle.net/uzpfxdgp/

Comment: You want a random category or a random item from all of the categories combined, or a random item for each category? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mapped = Object.keys(json).map(function(key, index){ return json[key]; })
                              .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); });

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * mapped.length);
console.log(mapped[index]);
```

Comment: This works! It's what I was looking for. Thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/uzpfxdgp/2/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but I think this might do the trick (where myObj is the object you included above).

```
var categoryArr = [];

for (var category in myObj) {
    categoryArr.push(myObj[category])
}

var randomObj = categoryArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryArr.length)];
```

Comment: The last `catArr` should be `categoryArr`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsFiddle that I created. Is that what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/Arllo/q66wkkmx/

```js
var list = {
  "category1": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #1"
    }
  ], 
  "category2": [
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #2"
    }, 
    {
      "Description": "Insert description here", 
      "Title": "Title #3"
    }
  ]
};
var numberOfProperties = Object.keys(list).length;
var randomProperty = Math.floor((Math.random() * numberOfProperties) + 1);
var randomCategory = "category" + randomProperty;
console.log(list[randomCategory]);
```

Comment: Close. I'm looking for one object from both categories. Your code returns both Title #2 and Title #3 from Category 2.